# TextInputLayout does not show hint in Edit Text

Tags: android, android-design-library

Below is the code that I am using. `TextInputLayout` is included as a part of Androids new *Design library*. But it does show the hint inside of the `EditText`. Am I using this the wrong way?
Once I click on the EditText the hint text animation works properly. Also when I click on some other EditText the hint text returns properly. So that is also not an issue. But I am not able to view the hint text in the first place.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/tilDrugName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtDrugName"
        style="@style/ETPrescription"
        android:hint="@string/drug_name"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: So can you see it or not? When `EditText` doesn't have any text - hint will show inside it. It moves out of `EditText` once you start typing/it has focus

Comment: I am not able to see the hint.

Comment: Can you also post a screenshot of your problem.

Comment: Update the design library to 22.2.1. `compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'` in your build.gradle.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have come across, this has been a bug in Android Support library for design.

[Android Source Bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175228)

So I think this will be resolved in upcoming updates.